# Linked list storing prime numbers from 1 to 1000

Tags: c, linked-list

As you will see in the comments of the following program, I am supposed to create a list that stores all prime numbers from 1 to 1000 and free the node.

Only two of of the functions are my work. However, I haven't figured out for ages why this program does not compile. Do you guys see the mistake? This is an already handed in homework, so this is just for my personal reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* given data structure declaration */
struct record {
  int             data;
  struct record * next;
};

typedef   struct record   RecordType;



/* DO NOT MODIFY */
/* print a list */
void print_list(RecordType * list)
{
  RecordType * visitor = list;
  int count = 0;

  while (visitor != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ", visitor->data);
    visitor = visitor->next;
    count++;
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("There are %d items in the list.\n", count);
}



/* MY WORK HERE */
/* free every node in the list */
void free_list(RecordType * list)
{
    while (list->data != 2){
        free(list->next);
        list->next = list;
    }
}

/* MY WORK HERE */
/* this function may call other functions created by students */
/* create a list storing all prime numbers in [1, 1000] in ascending order */
/* return a pointer to the starting point of the list */
RecordType * create_list_prime_in_1_to_1000()
{
    RecordType * begin, *tail, *temp;
    int i = 0;
    begin = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
    begin->data = 0;
    begin->next = NULL;
    tail = begin;
    while(i<1000){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
        temp -> data = ++i;
        tail -> next = temp;
        tail -> temp;
        tail -> next = NULL;
    }
}

int isPrime(int n){
    int d;

    for (d = 2; d < n; d = d + 1)
        if (n % d == 0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}





/* DO NOT MODIFY */
/* main program */
int main(void)
{
  RecordType * start;

  /* create a linked list to store all the prime numbers in 1 - 10 */
  /* this is a naive way by hard-coding */

  start = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
  start->data = 2;
  start->next = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
  start->next->data = 3;
  start->next->next = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
  start->next->next->data = 5;
  start->next->next->next = malloc(sizeof(RecordType));
  start->next->next->next->data = 7;
  start->next->next->next->next = NULL;

  print_list(start);

  free_list(start);


  /* i am expected to expected to build a list iteratively rather than hard-code */

  start = create_list_prime_in_1_to_1000();

  print_list(start);

  free_list(start);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error ? Post it too in the question, please.

Comment: The condition in the for loop of `isPrime` can be `d * d <= n` (think about why! :) ) will make the test much more efficient. (Also, `d = d + 1` == `d++`)

Comment: @dbaupp Or even better `++d`.

Comment: you guys are just so epic how did you guys just read this code in such a short time? just wow.. thanks alot guys! i'm going to absorb your tips first before asking any more followup question

Comment: error C2039: 'temp' : is not a member of 'record' this was the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `tail` declared as:

```
RecordType * begin, *tail, *temp;
```

and `RecordType` as:

```
struct record {
        int             data;
        struct record * next;
};    
typedef   struct record   RecordType;
```

Next you have:

```
tail -> temp;
```

which does not work as `RecordType` has no member named temp.

I think it should be:

```
tail = temp;
```

**The cause for the runtime error seems to be because of:**

```
void free_list(RecordType * list)
{
        while (list->data != 2){
                free(list->next);
                list->next = list;
        }
}
```

which is incorrect. You need something like:

```
void free_list(RecordType * list)
{
        // keep going till there are nodes.
        while (list){
                // save the link to the rest of the nodes.
                RecordType *temp = list->next;

                // free the current node.
                free(list);

                // repeat the process starting at the next node.
                list = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i think this makes whole lot more sense now. thanks!