# Insert prime number into Linked List

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, objective-c++

i can't write a complete c++ program that insert the prime numbers from 0 to 150 in order in a linked list object . the program should calculate 
- the sum of the element
-the aversge of the element

Comment: Please note that we do not provide code's from scratch. If you need some help, then show us what you have done, what problems you are exactly facing with the code and also about what you expect the program to do, indicating if there are any limitations. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I got that "I'm being asked to do someone's homework" feeling going on. Are you confused as to what steps you should take? Have you taken any steps and you are getting stuck somewhere?

Comment: i wanna to insert prime number from 0 to 150 in linked list 

and calculate the sum and the average of this linked list elements ?

Comment: Is your issue the linked list or determining if a number is prime?  Use `std::list` as your container.

Comment: So show us what you have tried.

Comment: yes ,, i confused ,, what steps should i take ,, :)

Comment: my issue is the linked list ,,, how implement it and insert this number in it ,,

Comment: I'd probably write some code to insert a specified number into a linked list. Then I'd write some code to determine whether a number is prime. Then I'd generate numbers from 0 to 150, check if they're prime, and if so insert them into the linked list.

Comment: Check out this similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350724/linked-list-storing-prime-numbers-from-1-to-1000. It will give you an idea about steps you need to take

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your homework is to use the std::list to help you find prime numbers. For each number from 2 to 150 divide it by all the primes you have found so far, if none of the primes divide into your number with out a remainder then you have just found another prime, add it to your list and keep going. Here it is in code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::list<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);      // start with first prime

    bool isPrime{false};
    for (int i=3; i<=150;++i) {
        isPrime=true;
        for (int n : primes) {
            if (i % n == 0)
            isPrime = false;
        }
        if (isPrime) primes.push_back(i);
    }

    int sum{0}, prod{1};
    for (int n : primes){
        sum += n;
        prod *= n;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The sum of primes is: " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The product of primes is: " << prod << std::endl;
}
```